# Truth set two variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could you explain how to do that?

```
Determine the truth set of 
y=x(x-4)
where x,y are from the universe of real numbers.
```

I tried writing that truth set=(0,4),(0,0),(32,8),(12,6) but I don't think that it's a good idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2} ~: ~y = x(x-4)\}.$

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Comment: @user2661923 so the answer is just like that? nothing more ?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the expression "*truth set*".  There could well be some training that you have been given that ascribes some special significance to the phrase that makes my response inappropriate.  Absent such a consideration, if I had to response to such a *test question*, in my ignorance, that would be my response.

Comment: Okay thank you a lot that helped.